# jQuery to add Browser-Name into css-class

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using jQuery to detect the Users Browser-Agent and than add the browser-name as a css-class to the body. This works like magic with webkit and mozilla … but with msie it fails — but don't know why. For msie i also have to add not only the «msie», but also one class with the version-number of the used msie (like «msie7» or «msie8»).

Everything works, only the msie-section does not!

my (full) jQuery-Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
(function($){
    $(function(){

        var $copy = $('div.SPA_printcontact').clone();
        var $body = $('body');

        $copy.insertAfter('#printdate');

        if($.browser.msie) {
            $body.addClass('msie')
            var userAgent = userAgent.substring(0,userAgent.indexOf('.'));
            var version = userAgent;
            $body.addClass('msie' + version)
        }
        if($.browser.webkit) {
            $body.addClass('webkit')
        }
        if($.browser.mozilla) {
            $body.addClass('mozilla')
        }

    });
}(jQuery));
-->
</script>
```

Comment: I know that it's not what you asked, but I feel obligated to point out, that your approach to (probably?) apply different styles to different browsers has some issues. Here's one of many articles written on this subject: http://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/

Comment: I'm pretending you did not hear about `$.browser.version`. I may be wrong. :) and what's `Everything works, only the msie-section does not!` ? Can you give us a hint on what's happening in IE?

Comment: Your script will fail for any browser you missed or any new version of IE which is bad design.

Comment: @polarblau & David: I know, I know, but that's right now the only way to go with this one SharePoint-Project … :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Try using $.browser.version to get the version no instead

EDIT: This has been deprecated in jQuery v1.9 and upwards. Please refer to Tom's answer below.

Comment: With $.browser.version I get the class into the body! YEAH! … BUT … it names «msie7.0» … this causes css-problems because of the «.» … how han I reduce the «msie7.0» to only add «msie7» or «msie8» etc.?

Comment: $.browser.version.replace(".0","");

Comment: Ok, I got it right with a mixture of your and Dr.Molle Answer: --- var userAgent = $.browser.version.substring(0,$.browser.version.indexOf('.'));} ---

Comment: this is now deprecated

Answer (score 2):

There is no global object `userAgent`. It's a member of `navigator`, so use `navigator.userAgent` instead or the version provide by jQuery like suggested by Mohib Sheth

Comment: I'm 100% sure that it will change everything. ` var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.substring(0,navigator.userAgent.indexOf('.'));`

Comment: sorry, the previous comment wasn't for you! ;-)

Comment: If I add navigator, I get «msie» AND «msieMozilla/4» … :-/

Comment: Ok, I got it right with a mixture of your and Mohib Sheth Answer: --- var userAgent = $.browser.version.substring(0,$.browser.version.indexOf('.'));} ---

Answer (score 0):

You can use Detectizr

https://github.com/barisaydinoglu/Detectizr

Detectizr is a Modernizr extension to detect

- device
- device model
- device orientation
- screen size
- operating system
- operating system version
- operating system version full
- browser
- browser version
- browser engine
- browser plugins

Detection of these sets are optional and can be disabled.

alternatively there is also http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/ which Detectizr is based on (is more light weight)

Answer (score -1):

Please try using $('body').addClass() if that does not work, then try $('body').attr("class",msie+version).

Comment: Read the example again, thats whats used, its only stored in a variable.