# CSS stylesheet for Opera, Safari and Chrome only

Tags: google-chrome, css, safari, opera

I'm using such code which works great on IE and Firefox:

```
 .tytulmalykom {
    color:#666666;
    font-size:11px;
    font-variant:small-caps;
}
```

I would like to use this code for Opera, Safari and Chrome only:

```
 .tytulmalykom {
    color:#666666;
    font-size:11px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

All my stylesheets are inside stylesheet.css file.

So far I'm using so many link rel's:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="files/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
<![if !IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="files/firefox.css" media="screen" /><![endif]>
<!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="files/ie7.css" /><![endif]-->
```

Comment: If this is your only style, why not just overwrite text-transform in your IE css and FF css?  By default, Opera, Safari and Chrome would get the styles.

Comment: Search for `css hacks` to get results like https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@document

Comment: I do not works. I've added the second code both to ie7.css and firefox.css and still `text-transform:uppercase` is being used.

Comment: Just add text-transform: none; to your IE and FF styles.

Comment: I've added `text-transform:none` a it's the same like at the beginning. Firefox, IE works ok, the rest is still using small-caps.

Comment: Is your css files being included in the order you listed above?  or are you including the FF/IE ones first?

Comment: It works for IE only, but as soon as I enter font-variant:small-caps; in firefox.css it doesn't work in Chrome/Opera/Safari.

Comment: I got it working in IE/Firefox/Safari/Chrome by adding small-caps and text-transform to ie7.css, then only small-caps in firefox.css, and finally only text-transform in stylesheet.css. The only problem is with Opera now: text is ok, but digits are very small...

Comment: You could detect the browser with Javascript and add a CSS class:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733691/jquery-to-add-browser-name-into-css-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what I did to solve this problem:

I've added on each page:

```
<style type="text/css">

@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
    .tytulmalykom { font-variant:small-caps; text-transform:none }
}
</style>
```

then

in stylesheet.css:

```
.tytulmalykom {
    color:#666666;
    font-size:11px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

and ie7.css:

```
.tytulmalykom {
    font-variant:small-caps;
}
```

nothing else needed in firefox.css